# E: Invalid operation instal

Tags: command-line, software-installation, oracle

I'm new to Ubuntu OS.

I wanted to install oracle 11g in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I followed the instructions on how to install oracle 11g on Ubuntu:

I've downloaded the oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip from ORACLE site, unzipped the zip file using `unzip oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip` command.

When I tried to run the next command (i.e., `sudo apt-get instal alien libaio1 unixodbc`), I was asked for my `sudo` password. Then I entered my administrator password but, I'm getting

```
E: Invalid operation instal
```

What could be the problem and how can I install SQL?

Comment: Change `instal` to `install`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a **typo error**, change:

```
 sudo apt-get instal alien libaio1 unixodbc
```

to:

```
 sudo apt-get install alien libaio1 unixodbc
```